# Remove option from mutable.Buffer

Tags: scala, collections

There is `headOption` method which returns `Option[T]` of the head of a collection.

I would like to have something like `removeOption(n: Int)` returning and removing n-th element if it's in range of the collection otherwise doing nothing and returning `None`.

I can do so with pattern matching, but this seems too messy. Maybe `implicit class`es would help here?

Actualyl I tried this:

```
 implicit class RemoveOptionImplicit[A](val t: mutable.Buffer[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def removeOption(index: Int) =
      if(index >= 0 & index < t.size)
        Some(t.remove(index))
      else
        None
  }
```

But not sure if this is a good way.

Comment: What should this list return? (standard-lists are immutable -> removing would have to create a new list).
Should it return a tuple of (Option[T], List[T])?

Comment: @ThomasBöhm It should return `Option[T]` where T is the element type. If exists `Some(el)`, `None` otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
import scala.util.Try
def safeRemove[A](mb: collection.mutable.Buffer[A], idx: Int): Option[A] =
  Try(mb.remove(idx)).toOption
```

It has the nasty side effect of mutating the `Buffer`, if the index is good, but I think that's what you asked for.

---

If you'd rather not deal with exceptions, your original idea can be simplified like so.

```
def safeRemove[A](mb: collection.mutable.Buffer[A], idx: Int): Option[A] =
  if (mb.isDefinedAt(idx)) Option(mb.remove(idx))
  else None
```

Of course pimping the `mutable.Buffer` methods via implicit conversion is always a possibility.

Comment: But if index is not good we catch the exception right? This is too slow I think.

Comment: I added some code to my question. Couldn't you please give some comment?

Comment: I came up with the second approach of @jwvh . I think you should use that.